# Why does the following Short ID generator always pause after a specific number of iterations

Tags: javascript

I am writing my own short Id generator. Running into some trouble testing the anticipated number of clashes, the script always seems to pause after a certain number of iterations. It prints 3.6999999999999997% clashes = 0 (that is after 37,000,000 iterations) and then pauses for a long time before printing 3.8% clashes = 0.

I have no real idea why this is?

```
var alreadyExistsCounter = 0;
var oneMillion = 1000000;
var iterations = oneMillion * 100;
var ALPHABET = '23456789abdegjkmnpqrvwxyz';
var hash = {};
var ID_LENGTH = 10;

var generate = function() {
        var rtn = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < ID_LENGTH; i++) {
        rtn += ALPHABET.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ALPHABET.length));
    }
    return rtn;
}

for (var i = 0; i < iterations;i++){

    var sh = generate();

    if (hash[sh]){ 
        alreadyExistsCounter = alreadyExistsCounter +1;
    }
    hash[sh] = true;
    if (i % 100000 === 0){
        var pct = i / iterations * 100;
        console.log( pct + '% clashes = ' + alreadyExistsCounter );
    }
}
```

Comment: it may be rehashing the hash table, or there might be a garbage collection cycle. Use the profiler in the Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks, never used the developer tools before what exactly do i need to do?

Comment: Here's the Chrome documentation on using profiling memory use: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling